# Compile one less-file into many css-files

Tags: css, less

Assuming we have a main.css, which has the following content (of course, this scenario is VERY simplified):

```
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

However, there are also themes, which have a different background-color.
So we end up having five different css-files:

- main.css
- main_blue.css
- main_red.css
- main_yellow.css
- main_green.css

But now it's really not maintainable anymore. If I have to change something in main.css, I also have to change the other files!

So I was browsing in the internet and had a glance at http://lesscss.org/ which seemed pretty promising.
However, neither do I know about how I could compile **one less-file into multiple css files**. Nor do I know if that would be the right approach.
The idea of declaring variables at the top of the css-file delights me, though.

So I wonder: Is LESS capable of solving this problem? (And if so, how?)
Or are there better ways to solve this?

Comment: Less can help you here. You can use variables in the main.less file and then have different values just for the variables in each individual theme file (along with a import reference to your main Less file) and while compiling, Less compiler can create different theme files for you depending on the variable value. Unfortunately, I am typing this from my hand-phone so can't give a working sample.

Comment: As @Harry said, you can use variables. Make one like `@mainColor: #someHEXValue;` and use that variable throught the whole stylesheet. And it's easy to change it, like `@mainColor: #newHEXValue;`

Comment: @Harry Thank you! I think I know exactly what you mean.
So I define variables in the main.less and when I import it I simply change the variables (if necessary)

Comment: @Vucko That's already clear to me. What I didnt grasp was the idea of importing the file and then only change the variables.

Comment: @fabigler: Yep mate. Like what Vucko has posted above, your main.less could have say `background-color: @theme-color` and in the blue theme file you assign `@theme-color: #00f;` and in the red them as `@theme-color: #f00;`. Less does lazy loading of variables and so the latest value defined for the variable would win.

Comment: @Harry That's really awesome, man! Lazy loading for Lazy programmers. Love it!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Harry's comment I ended up with the following solution:
For each theme simply create another .less-file with the following content:

```
@import "main.less";
@mainbackground-color: #96c8fd;
```

Note that more variables will follow after the import.